# Updating a CSV file once uploaded to private Shiny Server

Tags: r, csv, shiny, shiny-server

*Question is targeted at users experienced with shiny local server usage*

My Shiny app uses a large csv file to read all its data from to prevent it from  running a SQL command to get the same data everytime.

My question is once I have the app and all related files uploaded to my local shiny app server. Will I be able to locally write out from R to the csv file  on my server (updating it with fresh data). Without having to re upload the shiny server app with the new data files?

Apologies if this isn't in everyone's most preferred way to ask questions around here but its just a simple question to find out if it can be done.

Comment: Do you want to update the CSV file using a shiny app, or do you want your CSV file to be updated with the newest data from a SQL database? You can do either, but I'm not sure which action you want to take.